# Isolate scope behaves differently in angular 1.2.0rc3 and 1.2.14

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to Angular, and I am currently trying to understand angular directives. I am using angular 1.2.14 on my machine. I created two types of directives, one was created with `scope: {}` (isolated scope) and the another one was created with `scope: true` (inherit scope).

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Directive 10</title>
</head>
<body>

<div ng-init="myvar = 'MyVar!' "></div>
Level A : {{ myvar }}
<div my-true-dir>
  Level B : {{ myvar }}
</div>
<div my-obj-dir>
  Level C: {{ myvar }}
</div>

<script src="js/angular.js"></script>
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.directive('myTrueDir', function() {
  return {
    scope: true
  };
});
app.directive('myObjDir', function() {
  return {
    scope: {}
  };
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

According to the description in [ng-book](https://www.ng-book.com/), the isolate scope will not have access to the outer scope, vice versa. That mean in level 3, it is not supposed to have access to `myvar`, which is declared in the outer scope. But when I run the given code, I got this.

```
Level A : MyVar!
Level B : MyVar!
Level C: MyVar!
```

I thought it might be the ng-book's mistake, but when I run this code in angular.js 1.2.0rc3, the result was just as described in the ng-book, which is:

```
Level A : MyVar!
Level B : MyVar!
Level C:
```

Can anybody give a clue here?
The code and result with angular 1.2.14 can be [found here](http://jsbin.com/virurego/2/), and also the one with angular 1.2.0rc3 [can be found here](http://jsbin.com/jugur/1/).

Comment: did you try to define a template for these directives? also try to explicitly state the property within the isolated scope definition, i.e. `{myVar: '=myVar'}`. just checking if you were bitten by [this one](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/d0efd5eefcc0aaf167c766513e152b74dd31bafe)... see it in [the changelog](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#breaking-changes-6).

Comment: @EliranMalka Oh, yes. I didn't define a template. But this is not documented. It took me so long to figure this out. Thx!

Comment: sure. is this resolved as a consequence? i'll put it as an answer if so.

Comment: @EliranMalka sure, it is a bug, and fixed in 1.3.0beta1 :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have been bitten by [this regression](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/d0efd5eefcc0aaf167c766513e152b74dd31bafe) which was introduced in 1.2.0 (timely-delivery). Its due fix version is 1.3.0-beta.1.

See the [changelog entry](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#breaking-changes-6).

This change assumed (almost) nobody will be writing directives without defining templates, so to work around it, just add a template definition to your directives.